# I have just created small android project in Eclipse, which files I should add to version control?

Tags: android, eclipse, version-control

I have no idea, which files should be versioned for a new android project created in eclipse. Could anyone tell me, what I should add??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pretty much everything you need to build your project, including:

- `.project` and `.classpath` (yes, you should definitively add them, provided the .classpath doesn't include any absolute path: any other Eclipse users who would access your versioned project will thank you for that)
- [`.settings` content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445187/to-check-in-or-not-check-in-the-entire-eclipse-project/445252#445252) (for project Eclipse specific settings)
- other build-related files (like a `pom.xml`, if you have one)
- [launcher configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337304/which-eclipse-files-belong-under-version-control/337317#337317) (again, if you have some)

**Nothing that is generated** (like the [directory '`gen`'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615321/android-gen-folder-and-svn-bitter-enemies), or '`bin`') **should be added to source control**
[Workspace Eclipse metadata shouldn't be versioned either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468725/which-information-files-of-an-eclipse-workspace-should-be-tracked-by-source-con).

As I said in "**[Do you keep your project files under version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116121/do-you-keep-your-project-files-under-version-control/119377#119377)**", the goal is to ease and quicken the project setup process when checked-out in a workspace:

> "Load it up, set it up, go."

Comment: Should I really add .project? Isn't it specific for every user? I don't need to add files from `gen` and `bin` right?

Comment: Ok, that helps. But how about those: ? `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` and
`default.properties`?
And how the hell am I supposed to determine on my own, which files I am going to need?

Comment: @gruszczy: `.settings` is the second item on my list (I have added a link on it for you to review). Don't worry, simply all all its content. If somehow that introduce settings that are *too* local, you will be able to remove them later.

Comment: I am voting down, .project and .classpath are in fact always included in SCM..for the reason why just try to import a project where .project and .classapth are not SCm'd. After that pain of having to modify .project to insert correct project natures, etc you will understand why

Comment: @Fred: I am not sure I follow your reasoning: you shouldn't have to change anything, and I don't get the "`.project` and `.classapth` are not SCm'd": my answer is about having them under version control.