# Way to ignore files with Surround SCM?

Tags: ignore, svnignore, surroundscm

I am using surround SCM with a directory structure that looks like the following:

```
root/
  src/
    somecode/
  lib/
```

my working directory looks like this:

```
root/
  .settings/
  src/
    somecode/
  lib/
  someotherdirectory/
    file.txt
```

Basically, I don't want surround to report to me if my local copy of .settings (a directory) or file.txt have changed.  It seems simple - like an ignore in svn, but I can't seem to find a way to do it with surround.  I seem to have a lot of these local files around that don't need to be dealt with by the scm tool I'm using, and I'd prefer them not to show up in my recursive differences screen.

Any thoughts on how I might do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a way to emulate that feature would be to use [directory cloaking](http://www.seapine.com/scmconfigmgmt.html):

> Cloak repositories to skip them when recursively getting, checking in, checking out, or undoing checked out files. If a user does not work with specific repositories in Surround SCM, cloaking can shorten the time it takes to perform the get, check in, check out, and undo check out commands. It can also save local disk space by reducing cache needs.

So you could first get that directory, then cloak it.

Comment: Hm, ok.  That's a good suggestion.  Do you know if it's possible to ignore a specific file?  Basically, I'd like to ignore the .project file that we (erroneously... but it's not my decision) have checked into our repository.

Comment: @jwir: I didn't see any option to "cloak" just a file, though... Plus, I like when the `.project` is versioned ;) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725719/i-have-just-created-small-android-project-in-eclipse-which-files-i-should-add-to/3725787#3725787 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116121/do-you-keep-your-project-files-under-version-control/119377#119377

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Server Options dialog in the Surround SCM Client and navigate to the File Names/Extensions category. There is an "Ignore file or directory name" setting that allows you to perform this functionality. There is also an "Ignore file extension" setting that might be useful for things like .OBJ files.

As VonC pointed out, you could also use the cloak repository feature in Surround SCM, but you would need to do that for each instance of the .settings directory and you only cloak directories after they are added into the Surround SCM database. Using the ignore setting tells Surround SCM to apply this option to all instances and it is applied before the add operation occurs.

Comment: This doesn't help if your administrator has Server Options locked down.  This should be a client option, not a server option. :(

Comment: Agreed. Sadly, this answers the question with a resounding "No, you can't do this in SurroundSCM"

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the folder "hidden" on windows OS level,
that will also hide it for surround SCM.

Answer (score 0):

In earlier Surround SCM versions, there was only a server/mainline option to ignore files or directories, which was useful if all projects on that mainline applied the same ignore rules. Starting in Surround SCM 2019.1, in addition to the server/mainline options, there are two other methods to specify ignore rules.

1. Add repository-specific rules to ignore files and directories for recursively adding files, viewing working directory differences, and pushing changes to repositories. Rules are defined in .sscmignore files, which use a glob-style pattern and are stored in local working directories. Check in .sscmignore files if you want to share these rules with other team members.
2. Set user options to add user-specific rules to ignore files and directories for recursively adding files, viewing working directory differences, and pushing changes to repositories. These rules are specific to this user and are not shared across the team.