# GWT .hgignore / .gitignore entries

Tags: gwt, gitignore, hgignore, svnignore

What are the typical entries in your source control ignore files for a GWT App (developed in eclipse)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend:

- you [leave the eclipse files (.project, .classpath, ...) in your VCS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725719/i-have-just-created-small-android-project-in-eclipse-which-files-i-should-add-t/3725787#3725787),
- you ignore what is generated by GWT compilation, like in [this project](http://repo.or.cz/w/learning-gwt.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/.gitignore)
  (`.gitignore`)

:

```
/build
/classes
*.jar
*.class
*~
*/web-app/gwt
*/web-app/WEB-INF/classes
target
```

The name of certain generated directories can vary slightly, so you should adapt them for your project.

Comment: [they](http://repo.or.cz/w/learning-gwt.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/.gitignore) didn't include the `war` directory. Is it OK?

Comment: @RedPlanet it depends how your project is configured, but if you have a `war` directory, then yes, you can add `war/` to the `.gitignore` file content.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm making the first GWT project with [Google Maps](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/MapsGettingStarted) and only ignore `war/WEB-INF/classes/` and `gwt-unitCache/`.

Comment: @RedPlanet that should be enough, as long as you don't end up versioning *large* files which are re-generated at each build anyway.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to VonC's eclipse/ant/maven suggestions, I'd add the a few more gwt-specific entries:

- `.gwt` - compilation logs
- `gwt-unitCache` - caching for already compiled files
- `www-test` - gwt junit compilation files

Personally I'd stay away from trying to blacklist files/folders in any webapp dir, except either on a project-by-project basis, or by making sure that your compilation process builds gwt compiled files to another dir in a `build/` or `target/` dir - this might make things more annoying to start up, but you won't need to customize .gitignore with any new gwt module.